# stimulus controller in Rails 6 app not updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6, stimulusjs

Working through a tutorial and I am missing something.  There is a stimulus controller that is being developed to show/hide some content.  The first task was just to console.log out the word "Click!" to the console.

Now I have updated the controller to handle the show/hide behavior however the only thing that is happening is that is keeps console.logging out 'Click!'

I searched my app and found some files in the `.cache` in node_modules that had that code still in it so I removed that, it still appears now even though there is no reference to 'Click!' in the code at all.

Webpack is compiling without error (and has compiled many times asI have tried to debug this).

You can even see that the referenced line no longer matches

[image]

The controller is

```
import { Controller } from "stimulus"

export default class FavoriteToggleController extends Controller {
  static targets = ["elementToHide","elementWithText"] // Stimulus requires that any targets in use from the controller need to be declared in a static variable called 'targets'
  static values  = { visible: Boolean } 

  elementToHideTarget: HTMLElement // typescript visible declaration of the property
  elementWithTextTarget: HTMLElement

  visibleValue: Boolean

  connect(): void {
    this.updateHiddenClass()
    this.updateText()
  }

  toggle(): void {
    this.flipState()
    this.updateHiddenClass()
    this.updateText()
  }

  // functions
  flipState(): void {
    this.visibleValue = !this.visibleValue
  }

  visibleValueChanged(): void {
    this.updateHiddenClass()
    this.updateText()
  }

  updateHiddenClass(): void {
    this.elementToHideTarget.classList.toggle("hidden", !this.visibleValue)
  } 

  newText(): string {
    return this.visibleValue ? "Hide" : "show"
  }

  updateText(): void {
    this.elementWithTextTarget.innerText = this.newText()
  }
}
```

View

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag("favorite-concerts") do %>
  <section class="my-4" data-controller="favorite-toggle" data-favorite-toggle-visible-value="true">
    <div class="text-3xl font-bold"> 
      Favorite Concerts
      <button class="<%= SimpleForm.button_class %> py-1 text-xl font-semibold" data-action="favorite-toggle#toggle">  
        Hide
      </button>
    </div>
    <div data-favorites-tottle-target="elementToHide">
      <div class="text-xl font-bold" id="no-favorites">
        <% if current_user.favorites.empty? %>
          No favorite concerts yet
        <% end %>
      </div>
      <div id="favorite-concerts-list">
        <% current_user.favorites.each do |favorite| %>
          <%= render(favorite) %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
<% end %>
```

Folder structure

[image]

There are no errors in the console at all, just this old code that keeps executing.

I have done a hard refresh, restarted everything, nothing makes this go away.

Comment: Are you using Webpack? Have you tried to recompile your assets?

Comment: ya sorry updated the question, using webpack and it compiles, but that does not fix the issue

Comment: Could you please post the code of your view? And the folder/files structure?

Comment: My best guess is related to turbo-frame caching system. Have you tried to remove turbo_frame_tag? Additionally, have you tried to completely remove your `dist` folder?

Comment: @RockwellRice I had exactly the same problem in a rails project, and what worked for me was to upgrade the node version from v12 to v14.

Comment: I'm exploring something related to this.  My preliminary finding is that when a target is replaced by Turbo, `this.whateverTarget` stops working.  That's as far as I've gotten because I have some code I need to push out yesterday so I've resorted to using `document.getElementById` instead for now.

Comment: I got the same problem, tried all the solutions proposed in comments, and am still finding a solution... have you?

Comment: @Backo no, I just threw the book I was working from in the garbage and moved on to focusing on just using React.  Best of luck

Comment: @RockwellRice Let's !